# Routing directives are handled incorrectly despite not calling reject

Tags: scala, spray, spray-dsl

Could you please explain why minor modification completely breaks my routing ?

My routing is quite simple

```
val myRoutes =
  pathPrefix("MainService") {
    post {
      requestInstance {
        request =>
          XmlBody {
            (command, payload) =>
              ifTrue2(command, "login") {
                complete {
                  "Return something here"    
                }
              } ~
                ifTrue2(command, "serverInfo") {
                  complete {
                    "Return something here"
                  }
                } ~
                extractSession(payload) { // OLD VERSION WAS: myAuthorization {
                  session =>
                    complete {
                      "Return something here"
                    }
                }
          }
      }

// Where custom directives look like this

def myAuthorization = entity(as[NodeSeq]).flatMap[Session :: HNil](
  getSession(_) match {
    case Some(session) => provide(session)
    case None => reject(AuthorizationFailedRejection)
  }
)

def extractSession(xmlPayload: ⇒ NodeSeq): Directive1[Session] =
  getSession(xmlPayload) match {
    case Some(session) => provide(session)
    case None => reject(AuthorizationFailedRejection)
  }

def ifTrue2(cmd : String, target : String): Directive0 =
  new Directive0 {
    def happly(func: HNil ⇒ Route) = {
      if (cmd.equalsIgnoreCase(target))
        func(HNil)
      else
        reject
    }
  }

def XmlBody = entity(as[NodeSeq]).flatMap[String :: Node :: HNil](
  parseXmlRequest(_) match {
    case Some(result) => hprovide(result)
    case None => reject(BadXmlRejection("Bad XML body"))
  }
)

def parseXmlRequest(xmlData: NodeSeq): Option[String :: Node :: HNil] = // body omitted for simplicity
def getSession(xmlRequest: NodeSeq): Option[Session] = // body omitted for simplicity
```

It supports two unauthenticated calls `login` and `serverInfo`. All other requests must have sessionId inside.

What I describe below happens when client makes **only one** login request.

Presented code works for login request when I use version with `myAuthorization { }`. But it doesn't work with `extractSession(payload) { }`. `myAuthorization` imiplicitly takes `HttpEntity` as input.

What puzzles me the most is that directives under `ifTrue2` stopped working even though they have not changed. In debugger I see that `IfTrue2` is called twice as expected: with `("login", "login")` and `("login", "serverInfo")` parameters.

Why does it work differently ? What shall I do to fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

About bug in your new code (which causes an exception):

The [entity](http://spray.io/documentation/1.1-SNAPSHOT/spray-routing/marshalling-directives/entity/) directive takes payload from original http-request (it ignores results of `hprovide` - because it obviously can't understand hlists and works only with input request), your new code takes it from result of `parseXmlRequest`. That's the only difference.

Simply saying - now you're calling smthing like

```
 getSession(parseXmlRequest(request).payload) //it's now
```

instead of

```
 getSession(request.as[NodeSeq]) //it was before
```

So instead of `<Envelope><Headers>...</><Body><function><param1>...<param1>...</></></>` it passess `<param1>...</>...` to `getSession` and kills your SOAP-authorization (at least by loosing SOAP-headers and root tags) and i think throws an exception.

If you want to 'change' input request - use [`mapRequest`](http://spray.io/documentation/1.1-SNAPSHOT/spray-routing/basic-directives/mapRequest/) instead of `hprovide`

---

About your problem with custom directives:

`Spray` calculates **all** `directive`s, but **only one** appropriate `complete`, so you should catch exceptions inside your custom directive (one broken directive in any place may kill your whole routing):

```
def extractSession(xmlPayload: ⇒ NodeSeq): Directive1[Session] =
  try {
    getSession(xmlPayload) match {
      case Some(session) => provide(session)
      case None => reject(AuthorizationFailedRejection)
    }
  } catch {
    case t => reject(t)
  }
}
```

---

Example:

Actually i have ran your code with these mocks:

```
  def parseXmlRequest(xmlData: NodeSeq): Option[String :: Node :: HNil] = {Some(xmlData.text :: <None/> :: HNil)}

  def getSession(xmlRequest: NodeSeq): Option[Session] = { Some(Session())}
```

and received results as expected. But these mocks:

```
  def parseXmlRequest(xmlData: NodeSeq): Option[String :: Node :: HNil] = {Some(xmlData.text :: <None/> :: HNil)}

  def getSession(xmlRequest: NodeSeq): Option[Session] = { sys.error("Error")}
```

will always (even for login command) give you "InternalServerError" because you're not catching an exception inside directive.